# Is it possible to refresh multiple materialized views at once using a stored procedure in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I have multiple materialized views in postgresql (say view1, view2...view10). Now want to create stored procedure with merging all views so can refresh it

create or replace procedure create_views()
language plpgsql
declare
view1
view2

```
view10
```